Can i add a default value of an empty array in nodejs create item form?
Essentially i want to add a "posts" item for the users but have it default upon user creation as an empty array
const createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = {
      userName: req.body.userName,
      password: req.body.password,
      posts: req.body.posts,
    };
    const response = await mongodb.getDb().Db().collection('users').insertOne(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
};

I just want to add the default return as an array.

Where is the insertOne() or updateOne(). Read the basics in the official docs.

Not sure I'm following - you already initialize the user's posts with req.body.posts. Why not initialize it with [] instead?
